# Error while trying to compile pdf in Rstudio

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

Recently, trying to compile a PDF via Latex in R, I got the message in the title of this question. In addition to the above, I also got the image below:

[image]

The code used was this:

```
\documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,                   % tamanho da fonte
    openright,              % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    oneside,                    % para impressão em verso e anverso. Oposto a oneside
    a4paper,                    % tamanho do papel. 
    % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
    %chapter=TITLE,         % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %section=TITLE,         % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsection=TITLE,      % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,   % títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    % -- opções do pacote babel --
    english,                    % idioma adicional para hifenização
    %french,                    % idioma adicional para hifenização
    %spanish,               % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil                  % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    ]{abntex2}

% ---------------------
% Pacotes OBRIGATÓRIOS
% ---------------------
%\usepackage{lmodern}               % Usa a fonte Latin Modern
%\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}  %margens
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % fonte do arquivo
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfontsize}{\Large} % fonte do título
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{lastpage}               % Usado pela Ficha catalográfica
\usepackage{indentfirst}            % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
\usepackage{color}                  % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Inclusão de gráficos \usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{figs}              % path das figuras
\usepackage{epsfig,subfig}          % Inclusão de figuras
\usepackage{microtype}              % Melhorias de justificação
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter} % remove o número do capítulo das equações
%\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}  % add the chapter number
% ---------------------

% ---------------------
% Pacotes ADICIONAIS
% ---------------------

%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}  % Comandos matemáticos avançados 
%\usepackage{setspace}                      % Para permitir espaçamento simples, 1 1/2 e duplo
%\singlespacing   %Para um espaçamento simples
%\onehalfspacing  %Para um espaçamento de 1,5
%\DoubleSpacing   %Para um espaçamento duplo. DS maísculos para esse tido de doc
\usepackage{verbatim}                   % Para poder usar o ambiente "comment"
\usepackage{tabularx}                   % Para poder ter tabelas com colunas de largura auto-ajustável
\usepackage{afterpage}                  % Para executar um comando depois do fim da página corrente
\usepackage{url}                        % Para formatar URLs (endereços da Web)
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}       % Para sinal (-) nos números.
\usepackage{soul, soulutf8}             % gerar marcador de texto
\usepackage{float}                      % pra gerir a posição dos gráficos e tabelas
\usepackage{multirow}                   % mult linhas nas tabelas
\usepackage{threeparttable}             % tabelas com 3 partes
%\usepackage[textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}                   % altera a fonte do título
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont}    % remove o negrito de seções
%\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{caption,multicol,booktabs,array}

% ---------------------

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox} % ajusta o quadros e tabelas
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % negrito nas legendas
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false % <-- important
]{caption}
%\usepackage{floatrow} % permite que as legendas fiquem na parte superiro de quadros e tabelas



\newcommand{\quadroname}{Quadro}
\newcommand{\listofquadrosname}{Lista de quadros}

\newfloat{quadro}{loq}{\quadroname}
\setfloatadjustment{quadro}{\centering}
\newlistof{listofquadros}{loq}{\listofquadrosname}
\newlistentry{quadro}{loq}{0}
\renewcommand{\cftquadroname}{\quadroname\space} 
\renewcommand{\cftquadroaftersnum}{\hfill\textendash\hfill}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{quadro}{htbp}{loq}
\floatname{quadro}{Quadro}
%\newcommand{\listofquadros}{\listof{quadro}{Lista de Quadros}}
\captionsetup[quadro]{listformat=simple}

%\usepackage{newfloat} % lista de quadros
%\PrepareListOf{quadro}{%
%\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Quadro~}}
% Corrigindo para que apareça o nome Quadro ao invés de Figura
%\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
%fileext=loq,
%listname={Lista de Quadros},
%name=Quadro,
%placement=p,
%within=section,
%chapterlistsgaps=off
%]{quadro}
% ---------------------
% Pacotes de CITAÇÕES
% ---------------------
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}    % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}               % Citações padrão ABNT (alfa)
%\usepackage[num]{abntex2cite}              % Citações padrão ABNT (numericas)
\usepackage{endnotes}
%\let \footnote=\endnote 
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}  % Reset endnote numbering every new chapter
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Notas}
%\usepackage{pagenote}
%\makepagenote
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ---------------------



% O tamanho da identação do parágrafo é dado por:
\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}

% Controle do espaçamento entre um parágrafo e outro:
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}  % tente também \onelineskip

% ---------------------
% Compila o índice
% ---------------------
\makeindex
% ---------------------



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  INICIO DO DOCUMENTO  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    
    % Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.
    \frenchspacing
    
    % ----------------------------------------------------------
    % ELEMENTOS PRÉ-TEXTUAIS (Capa, Resumo, Abstract, etc.)
    % ----------------------------------------------------------
    \pretextual
    
    
\end{document}
```

I was able to compile, but when changing the HD to an SDD, and the operating system, the mentioned message appears. How to proceed properly about this problem?

Comment: The code you show works as such, but it does not have any content in the body, so the resulting pdf will be empty. Try with some random words in the body and see if you'll get a valid pdf